# Object warping when I try to scale along one axis

Tags: scale

I am trying to scale a number of joined objects but when I scale them along one axis the mesh warps in a strange way. How can I prevent this from happening and get my object to scale correctly?[image: Pre-scale]

[image: Post-scale]

Comment: Are you using the Ctrl key while scaling? If so, the mesh will snap to the nearest vertex according to your 'Snapping' settings.

Comment: No but when I do that the mesh warps and rotates in the opposite direction.

Comment: Try applying scale first by Ctrl+A